# The border lines in my Nav bar have a slight margin to the right of them

Tags: html, css

The borderlines in my Navagation Bar have a little margin after them. You can see them by hovering over elements in the nav bar. It makes the animations 
I put in place seem ugly. Is there any way to solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
   @keyframes antimouse {
     0% { background-color: #2F9EBD;
       height: 45px} 
     100% {
       background-color:#35B1C2;
       height:20px;}
   }

   @keyframes mouse {
     0% { background-color:#35B1C2;
     height:20px}
     100% { background-color: #2F9EBD;
     height: 45px
      }
   }




 ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
   overflow:visible;
   height:48px; 
   background-color:#35B1C2;
   text-align: center;
 }
   li{
     text-align: center;
     display: inline-block;
    }


   li a {
     display: inline-block;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
   }
   li a {
     animation-fill-mode:forwards;
     animation-duration: 0.5s;
     animation-name: antimouse;
   }

   li a:hover {
       animation-fill-mode:forwards;
       animation-duration: 0.5s;
       animation-name: mouse;
   }

   li {
     border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
   }

   li:last-child {
     border-right: none;
   }

 </style>

 </head>

 <body>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>

      </ul>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here's a little tip.  In today's day and age, you do not need to include the `<html>` tags if you use the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag at the start.  You can go straight into the `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the linebreaks between the `li` elements, like this:

```
<ul><li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li><li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li></ul>
```